# ViewModel with checkbox boolean and paging

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, viewmodel, pagedlist

Perhaps I am misunderstanding how a `ViewModel` works. A `ViewModel` is used to display custom data to the user without having to use the full `Model`. So you would use only the database fields that you want displayed. I have a ViewModel that looks like this

```
using PagedList;
using Resolutions.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Resolutions.ViewModels
{
    public class SearchPagingViewModels
    {
        public int ObjectID { get; set; } //Database Primary Key
        [DisplayName("Resolution Year")]
        public string ResolutionYear { get; set; } //Year of the Resolution
        [DisplayName("Resolution Number")]
        public string ResolutionNumber { get; set; } //Number of the Resolution
        [DisplayName("Resolution Text")]
        public string ResolutionText { get; set; } //OCR'd text for the Resolution
        [DisplayName("Resolution Date")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ResolutionDate { get; set; } //Date of the Resolution
        public int? PageNumber { get; set; }
        public bool? IsResYearChecked { get; set; }
        public bool? IsResNumChecked { get; set; }
        public bool? IsKeywordChecked { get; set; }
        public string SearchKeyword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to store the value of a checkbox from the client side into my object and use the boolean to be able to filter and page through the results. However, if I use my current `ViewModel` I get 25 checkboxes when I try to access the object's `boolean`; As I can only seem to access the value of the checkbox within a `foreach` loop that I am using to display each item. I am currently pulling information from a database and then storing the database results into a list of the `ViewModel`.

This is my controller:

```
using PagedList;
using Resolutions.Models;
using Resolutions.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Resolutions.Controllers
{
    public class SearchPagingController : Controller
    {
        private DocumentManagementEntities db = new DocumentManagementEntities();

        // GET: SearchPaging
        public ViewResult Index(int? page, bool? resnum)
        {
            var temp = resnum;
            int pageSize = 25;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

            List<SearchPagingViewModels> searchList = new List<SearchPagingViewModels>();
            var allResolutions = from c in db.AllResolutions select c;
            allResolutions = allResolutions.OrderBy(c => c.ResolutionYear).ThenBy(c => c.ResolutionNumber);
            foreach (var item in allResolutions)
            {
                SearchPagingViewModels searchItem = new SearchPagingViewModels();
                searchItem.ObjectID = item.ObjectID;
                searchItem.ResolutionYear = item.ResolutionYear;
                searchItem.ResolutionNumber = item.ResolutionNumber;
                searchItem.ResolutionText = item.ResolutionText;
                searchItem.ResolutionDate = item.ResDate;
                searchItem.IsResNumChecked = resnum;
                searchList.Add(searchItem);
            }


            return View(searchList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I create a `List<SearchPagingViewModels>` and then add each `SearchPagingViewModels` into the `List<SearchPagingViewModels>`. In my `Index.cshtml`, I use a `foreach` loop to traverse the list and display each item and create a `PagedList`. Should I be changing my `ViewModel` to store a `List<AllResolutions>` like so:

```
using PagedList;
using Resolutions.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Resolutions.ViewModels
{
    public class SearchPagingViewModels
    {
        public List<AllResolution> AllResolutions { get; set; }
        public int? PageNumber { get; set; }
        public bool? IsResYearChecked { get; set; }
        public bool? IsResNumChecked { get; set; }
        public bool? IsKeywordChecked { get; set; }
        public string SearchKeyword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

or do I want to use the current values within the `ViewModel`? If instead I used a `List<AllResolutions>`, how do you access the values within the list in the `cshtml` file?

Comment: Your 2nd view model is correct, but there are other issues with your code. Is the purpose of `IsResYearChecked` to filter the results - for example if you check that checkbox, then you want to filter `allResolutions.Where(x => x.someProperty = true)`? - its unclear what the checkboxes relate to and what they are used for since they do not seem to relate to model properties

Comment: I am trying to create a search function that will return the results for whichever checkbox is checked. So if resyear and resnum are checked it would return those results. Where x contains keyword

Comment: Still not clear. Are you saying that if you check the `IsResYearChecked` checkbox, and all the others are unchecked, then you only want to display that column and not the others? (that makes no sense)

Comment: If `IsResYearChecked` is checked it would display all of the columns and it would filter the results that would contain the `SearchKeyword` string

Comment: So you have a textbox for `SearchKeyword ` in the view, and if `IsResYearChecked`  is checked, then you would query `allResolutions.Where(x=> x.ResolutionYear.Contains(SearchKeyword));`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171121/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kevorski).